# Email verification without having a FirebaseUser

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to send a verification email without having a firebaseUser, is it possible ?
I know i can do it with user.sendEmailVerification() method but can i do it just by giving an email from a textfield ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I knew and what I've read from the documentation, it looks like it's not possible to do this. A Firebase user, a.k.a an user authenticated within Firebase platform is required if you want to send email verification that uses Firebase Email Vetification service.

Well, do not lose hope since there are plenty workarounds to do this. What I would do to achieve this is to use Firebase Cloud Functions to create serverless API platform. I connect Firebase Cloud Functions with Firebase Admin SDK (which also has access to other Firebase services if I am not mistaken).

I send an email using some kind of email service providers such as SendGrid to designated email address (which the app got from user's inputted email) and provide a link to verify there (in the e-mail that sent to designated email address). Then, in the cloud functions, you leverage Firebase Admin SDK to change verification status.

This approach is flexible though, as it can be used to verify a user not only with Firebase Authentication.

Hope it helps. If it's not clear for you, just comment.
Happy coding.

**EDIT: After thoroughly read your question again, I realized that my answer is not fully correct. Somehow you still need a specific user to be added within Firebase Authentication database, which you would not want to do manually and let your app do so instead. Perhaps you can use Firebase Admin SDK in this matter. You can read official Firebase documentation for more information regarding Admin SDK.**

Comment: I found this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link , do you think it's possible to generate an email verification link and send it, each time an email is added into a firestore collection ? Because i think if it's possible, i will neste this code in a firestore trigger, that trigger every time an email is added.

Comment: With this, i think i don't really need a user to be added within Firebase Authentication

Comment: If you read the docs carefully, they said **provide the existing user’s unverified email** and **The email used must belong to an existing user.**, which I think it means that the workaround you are going to do is not going to work. Firebase Admin will link up the submitted email with the similar email that exists within Firebase Authentication database, then if the link up is success, it will generate an email verification link which then you can send using custom email service/SMTP server.

Comment: By the way, did you use Firebase Authentication at all? Because if you don't, then you may prefer to develop your own user verification system. It's not hard by the way. For example: OTP verification. You can use SendGrid/any similar provider, take any user's email, send an OTP to that user's email. You can store the OTP in a Firestore collection named OTP or anything you like. If the OTP entered by the user matches, then you can confirm that user as verified.

Comment: Oh alright, yes i did use Firebase Authentication but it's alright i just had to find a way to make sure that the user did receive his email verif

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I think Firebase Authentication is pretty reliable; I also used them across several mobile app projects of mine, and leveraged Firebase Admin SDK to verify users. Every signed up/newly signed in users always got their account verification email and rarely failed. You should put up some UI/mechanism to auto-retry email verification sending in your app. Cheers!